# Oracle - is daily partitioning approach good for table with millions of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, database-performance, sqlperformance

I am working on a existing table which has millions of rows of data, in terms of retail transactions history. the schema looks like below :

```
create table History(
hid number(19,0),
type varchar2(255 char),
lastupdated timestamp (6) not null enable,
name varchar2(255 char),
primary key (hid))
partition by range (lastupdated) interval (numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
(partition retailhistory values less than (to_timestamp('12/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')));
```

The above table is partitioned based on daily interval partitioning, So there would be 365 partitions in a year consisting millions of rows. We are planning to create a purging job but until then will it be ok to have this much partitions in a table, and will it cause performance degrade compared to a table with no partitions?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think that is a good plan, I do partitioning by day and hour as we add around add 4-5 millions rows per day in data warehouse .

Comment: For "million of rows" in total, you don't usually need partitioning. If you mean "million of rows per day", then partitioning might help, but only if your queries always include the partitioning key. If you do range queries across a wide range of days, it will probably make things a bit slower  to query, but will help in removing old rows.

Comment: I have a table with 6 months daily partitions and each partition has 99 subpartitions, so 18'000 partitions in total. There is no problem.

Comment: @Shweta . . . This is pretty much what partitioning is designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "millions", daily partitioning may be too granular and may cause performance problems when reading data.

Each partition is physically stored like a table and has different overheads - most importantly the overhead for segment space allocation. Oracle almost never allocates *exactly* how much space is needed, there's always a little extra. If you create a large number of tiny partitions, that "little extra" can be larger than the actual data.

In my below test case, assuming 5 million rows per year, and a relatively small value in each of the columns, daily partitioning uses ten times more segment space than monthly partitioning. This means daily partitioning will be optimal for selecting a single day of data, but will be terrible for selecting multiple days of data. And since full table/partition scans use multi-block reads, and read megabytes of data at a time anyway, reading a whole month of data may not be much slower than reading a day of data anyway.

### Sample Schema

Create three tables for daily, monthly, and no partitioning. Load 5 million rows equally into each of the 365 days, and then check the segment sizes.

- Daily partitioning uses 2,920 megabytes for 365 segments.
- Monthly partitioning uses 288 megabytes for 13 segments.
- No partitioning uses 280 megabytes for 1 segment.

Code:

```
----------------------------------------
--DAY
----------------------------------------

create table History_day(
hid number(19,0),
type varchar2(255 char),
lastupdated timestamp (6) not null enable,
name varchar2(255 char),
primary key (hid))
partition by range (lastupdated) interval (numtodsinterval(1,'day'))
(partition retailhistory values less than (to_timestamp('12/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')));

create sequence history_day_seq;

begin
    for i in 1 .. 365 loop
        for j in 1 .. 13698 loop
            insert into history_day values(history_day_seq.nextval, 'some type value', date '2020-12-01' + i, 'some name value');
        end loop;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/

select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb, count(*) partition_count from dba_segments where segment_name = 'HISTORY_DAY';


----------------------------------------
--MONTH: 288 megabytes for 13 partitions.
----------------------------------------

create table History_month(
hid number(19,0),
type varchar2(255 char),
lastupdated timestamp (6) not null enable,
name varchar2(255 char),
primary key (hid))
partition by range (lastupdated) interval (numtoyminterval(1,'month'))
(partition retailhistory values less than (to_timestamp('12/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY')));

create sequence history_month_seq;

begin
    for i in 1 .. 365 loop
        for j in 1 .. 13698 loop
            insert into history_month values(history_month_seq.nextval, 'some type value', date '2020-12-01' + i, 'some name value');
        end loop;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/

select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb, count(*) partition_count from dba_segments where segment_name = 'HISTORY_MONTH';


----------------------------------------
--NO PARTITIONS
----------------------------------------

create table History(
hid number(19,0),
type varchar2(255 char),
lastupdated timestamp (6) not null enable,
name varchar2(255 char),
primary key (hid));

create sequence history_seq;

begin
    for i in 1 .. 365 loop
        for j in 1 .. 13698 loop
            insert into history values(history_seq.nextval, 'some type value', date '2020-12-01' + i, 'some name value');
        end loop;
    end loop;
    commit;
end;
/

select sum(bytes)/1024/1024 mb, count(*) partition_count from dba_segments where segment_name = 'HISTORY';
```

### Do these results apply to you?

There's a good chance your results will be different on your system, depending on your data and how your system allocates segments. The important thing is that you should perform a test like this yourself. And keep in mind that partitions are designed for "large" amounts of data - but the word "large" is clearly subjective.

Daily partitioning is perfect for many large tables, but I have a feeling that your table would work better with month partitioning.

Comment: Mr. Jon, how can I create a partition by date range in intervals of one month and a subpartition by day or list by day, can you? How would the performance be? since monthly I want to move the oldest partition to another tablespace

Comment: @VictorMarrerp You should ask this as a separate question. But I think the answer is that it's not possible to have multiple interval schemes, and there's probably no huge advantage to partitioning by both month and day anyway. If you have day partitioning, then partition pruning can retrieve only the relevant days if a query asks for a month of data. Moving multiple day partitions instead of one month partition will be more work, but not significantly more.